# Channel form submit / return issues

Tags: safecracker

I'm currently trying to do quite a few things with Channel Form - unfortunately all of a sudden I'm starting to get some odd things happening. Instead of the page submitting nicely the url is doing this:

http://networkleeds.local/content?RET=http%3A%2F%2Fnetworkleeds.local%2Fcontent&URI=content&return_url=%2Fcontent%2Fpayment%2FENTRY_ID&author_id=1&channel_id=7&entry_id=0&ACT=2&meta=qDIxJOIvLN55gCICn%2BLSWCpg6AAVGjQOM38I8s7BJOTAv9ca1mKfPShy1s5pi8UjB58zSLf%2Br6nVBM6P4Q2Wb%2BiZhxRZCj8hlOnzhfICIRzA0s9M6ZGAn4IrnM2k7xr7XcvveK%2BnIVzajgE7x57v4PyY8ugnFm1lDsKTUZoEokwflILWFqjQf7Tf7odrx34V4NjbhHRkMRcYHzfgqdwHobi7hd%2BoAU7%2BGtq2wIywsZtvqKfsb4V7j7RuL%2BJUNgDDuCgDqz9VY4IGPjBJej2bjr63ljfaLAx2X36cwbJU4Pp5HQAA1VdVeS4xdj%2FAuWx6U2zzP8%2Bfnz%2BNP966nHBvXmbeplvj%2F0nqxJQEmJ4E%2BliY7bcaqh4zgmiVKWbVYZsMig9Yu8QGGGgo1JuDARJXb1hNeMzFNOWEQDyYwheQ0me%2BTS%2B1TjgfwujJ6xL%2FXwut82UWCN6CVzvRr0UdmaqnBg1tGHljXpcZ3lMcH646nbrGsuDs95eIu2Qwxt2wh6yLYzxhIruTC655JVNei2r9xhTpsmqd3DkiTJqW5cXh5tbyRvhnXpsBqjglqhxiu6Zis42bT1XQ4L73L5miVIxuGwwpv7szfgWCmKn7thwInPIKs8H4N%2F95dxdXLBu6XSsSPNYdfnZXgOx2ciM%2FCqxDaZyCOeXMOlFrhItnXgzCzp4%3D&return=%2Fcontent%2Fpayment%2FENTRY_ID

For some of my channels it is working fine - but as far as I can tell I haven't changed anything for the other ones. If I look at the code produced it seems to be that the action on the generated form tag is creating this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I would also appreciate the help.

Comment: similar issue here but channel forms work fine, I have the issue with zoo visitor new membership foirms

Comment: Dan, did you ever find a solution to all that junk in the action parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to track down why the action URL was being changed. Turns out if any custom fields are file type then this happens.

Channel_form_lib.php - Line 2195

```
if (in_array($row['field_type'], $this->file_fields))
{
    $this->file = TRUE;
}
```

And then line 761

```
if ($this->file)
{
    $action = $hidden_fields;
    $action_url = $action['RET'];
    $action['ACT'] = ee()->functions->insert_action_ids($action['ACT']);
    $action = $action_url . '?' . http_build_query($action);
}
```

In response to the original question, I don't think the action URL is the problem. Rather, somehow you're stopping at that URL rather than being redirected to the return_url. Hopefully this helps someone else since you've probably resolved your issue already.